# Узнать было ли изменено направление персонажа и какое

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
private void Update()
{
    _direction.x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * _characterContract.MoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    _direction.z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * _characterContract.MoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

    if (Vector3.Angle(Vector3.forward, _direction) > 1.0f || Vector3.Angle(Vector3.forward, _direction) == 0.0f)
    {
        _lookDirection = Vector3.RotateTowards(transform.forward, _direction, _characterContract.MoveSpeed, 0.0f);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(_lookDirection);
    }

    _characterController.Move(_direction);
}
```

У меня есть код перемещения объекта. Мне нужно получить true, если направление движения было изменено, но небыли отпущены клавиши. Движение происходит по WASD, если игрок остановился, я знаю как это проверить, а если игрок двигается, но резко поменял направление. Это не знаю как отловить. И какое именно направление у него было и стало... Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Угол между двумя векторами посчитать?

Comment: Если угол между векторами 0 градусов, то персонаж направляется туда, куда и шел. А если больше 0 - то поменял направление? И сразу старое направление присваивать к новому и снова сравнивать. Так?